# Get Process Mutex List

Tags: c#, .net, list, process, mutex

I got a List of Process IDs and I want to list all the mutexes owned by this process.

I am trying to do this in C#, but I just can't find a way to do this.

So far i got:

```
foreach(Process thisProcess in processlist)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", thisProcess.ProcessName, thisProcess.Id);
}
```

That will list all Process IDs, but need the mutexes that are owned by them.

I read something about using a NTDLL.dll but dont now how to.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerating Mutexes is part of general working with "kernel objects". Reading [the book- "Windows Internals"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx) is good idea before diving into such code.

Here is a link that give [some info](http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic9529.html) about [enumerate kernel object](http://www.bing.com/search?q=enumerate++kernel+object+&qs=HS&form=QBRE&pq=enumerate+kernel+object)

> use  ZwQuerySystemInformation with SystemHandleInformation, ZwDuplicateObject, ZwQueryObject with ObjectNameInformation.

Comment: I Just Did all That, But some Mutex Return a Name with the ObjectNameInformation doing something like ZwQueryObject(hObject, ObjectNameInformation, oni, n, &n); and oni[0].name, but other mutex wont return no name at all. Any help With this. I tried on a mutex i created and yes i can find the mutex but no name

Comment: I don't know... Fortunately I never needed to dig into this stuff myself.

Comment: Mutexes don't have to have names.